# Adding background image to markers in jvectormap

Tags: svg, jvectormap

Found a couple of solutions here about adding SVG patterns dynamically but it doesn't seem to work with jvectormap. I think the problem may be that there is no `XMLNS` attribute defined on the `<SVG>` tag by jvectormap but my attempt to add these attributes does not work.

I also tried changing all of the `setAttribute` to `setAttributeNS` for `pattern` and `image`. But no dice.

Here is my attempt (based on this solution: [How to dynamically change the image pattern in SVG using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378797/how-to-dynamically-change-the-image-pattern-in-svg-using-javascript)):

```
// Set namespace for SVG elements.
var svgMap      = $('.jvectormap-container > svg').get(0);
var svgNS       = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var svgNSXLink  = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';

svgMap.setAttribute('xmlns',        svgNS);
svgMap.setAttribute('xmlns:link',   svgNSXLink);
svgMap.setAttribute('xmlns:ev',     'http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events');

// Create pattern for markers.
var pattern     = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'pattern');
pattern.setAttribute('id',          'markeryellow');
pattern.setAttribute('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse');
pattern.setAttribute('width',       '38');
pattern.setAttribute('height',      '38');

// Create image for pattern.
var image       = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'image');
image.setAttribute('x',             '0');
image.setAttribute('y',             '0');
image.setAttribute('width',         '38');
image.setAttribute('height',        '38');
image.setAttributeNS(svgNSXLink, 'xlink:href', '/path/to/image.png');

// Put it together
pattern.appendChild(image);

var defs        =
    svgMap.querySelector('defs') ||
    svgMap.insertBefore(document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'defs'), svgMap.firstChild);
defs.appendChild(pattern);

var $markers    = $(svgMap).find('.jvectormap-marker');
$.each($markers, function(i, elem) {
    $(elem)
        .attr({
            'fill':     'url(#markeryellow)'
        });
});
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to achieve the same thing but no luck so far!