# Load a new IMG as pattern into a SVG

Tags: svg

Into my page I have a SVG image wth 3 path then on other side I have 3 buttons. On click on each button I want apply a pattern to my SVG's path.

The script I did not works completly. It update the SVG structure adding all the necessary code but the result miss the image.

**UPDATE** Here the demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/756DS/

If on debug I copy the new SVG code and open it in a new window I see the result I want. But on live...  it wont load the img pattern. Here the heart of my script:

> ```
>       var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
>
> var img = document.createElementNS(svgns,'image');
>           img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','536');
>           img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','536');
>           img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','xlink:href',pattern_url);
>           img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','-81');
>           img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','-81');
>           img.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');  
>           
>
>           def= document.createElementNS(svgns,'defs');
>   
>           pattern = document.createElementNS(svgns,'pattern');
>
>
>           pattern.setAttributeNS(null,'id','img_pattern');
>           pattern.setAttributeNS(null,'patternUnits','userSpaceOnUse');
>           pattern.setAttributeNS(null,'width','600');
>           pattern.setAttributeNS(null,'height','450');
>           
>           pattern.appendChild(img)
>
>           def.appendChild(pattern)
>           
>       
>           side_1 = document.getElementById('side_1');
>           side_1.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","url(#img_pattern)")
>           
>           side_2 = document.getElementById('side_2');
>           side_2.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","green")
>           
>           side_3 = document.getElementById('side_3');
>           side_3.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","url(#img_pattern)")
> ```

On this test only the "fill","green" works.

Can you hep me ?

Comment: You might need to look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378797/how-to-dynamically-change-the-image-pattern-in-svg-using-javascript

Comment: Hello, thanks for help.  I did it but I was unable to do... I'm svg.querySelector('defs') ("svg.querySelector is not a function") (?!)

Comment: What is 'svgns' set to?  Can you post the SVG file you are trying to modify?

Comment: Here a demo:   http://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/756DS/

Comment: @BigBadaboom  Thanks! The bug was there! the NS I used was not load so it was not working:  var svgns = svg.namespaceURI ( it was undefined!)  instead :  var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; was fixing!  THANKS!!!  But now, just if you have free time...   can you check my SVG declaration ? Why it was undefined ?

Comment: Because you are trying to read it from the jQuery object and not the DOM Node.  Try `var svgns = svg.get(0).namespaceURI` instead.